# Left join with date and ID column

Tags: python, pandas

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1izDH.jpg)[[image: left null join]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1izDH.jpg)

Let's say this is CSV1:

> STARTDATE | ENDDATE | ITEMID | CSV1UQID
>
> 1999-09-27 | 9999-12-31 | 100000 | 121
>
> 1999-10-27 | 9999-12-31 | 100001 | 123
>
> 1222-09-27 | 9999-12-31 | 999999 | 125

and CSV2:

> CSV2STARTDATE | CSV2ENDDATE | ITEMID
>
> 1998-09-27 | 9999-12-31 | 100000
>
> 1999-10-27 | 9999-12-31 | 100001

I would like to join these tables based on their columns, specifically STARTDATE, ENDDATE, or ITEMID in their differences, to show if their are differences unique for dataframes. I shortened the original data frames csv1 and csv2 respectively as they include 5000+ rows, so it would be good for the data to be displayed neatly.

These are the results I would like to produce 
Left Join Null (aka. CSV1 exclusives):

> > STARTDATE | ENDDATE | ITEMID | CSV1UQID
> >
> > 1999-09-27 | 9999-12-31 | 100000 | 121  (this row is in left join, null because the start date is unique to CSV1 in comparison to CSV2STARTDATE)
> >
> > 1222-09-27 | 9999-12-31 | 999999 | 125 (because all of the parameters are unique to CSV1)

However, so far my code is this for left-join (null):

```
csv1iID = csv1.set_index('ITEMID')
csv2iID = csv2.set_index('ITEMID')

CSV1only = csv1.join(
    csv2iID,
    on = 'ITEMID', 
    lsuffix = '_l',
    rsuffix = '_r',
).query('ITEMID_r.isnull()')
```

But this only produces:

> STARTDATE | ENDDATE | ITEMID | CSV1UQID
>
> 1222-09-27 | 9999-12-31 | 999999 | 125

because it only looks at ITEMID differences, instead of date as well. How could I fix this so that it is the desired result?

> > See the row that has >>

Answer (score 0):

The indicator parameter of the outer join will return whether the values are in left, right, or both.  You can filter the resulting df by `df['_merge'] == 'left_only'` to get the left only records, etc.

df1

```
STARTDATE       ENDDATE     ITEMID  CSV1UQID
0   1999-09-27  9999-12-31  100000  121
1   1999-10-27  9999-12-31  100001  123
2   1222-09-27  9999-12-31  999999  125
```

df2

```
STARTDATE       ENDDATE     ITEMID
0   1998-09-27  9999-12-31  100000
1   1999-10-27  9999-12-31  100001


df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['STARTDATE','ENDDATE','ITEMID'], indicator=True)
```

Output

```
    STARTDATE   ENDDATE     ITEMID  CSV1UQID    _merge
0   1999-09-27  9999-12-31  100000  121.0       left_only
1   1999-10-27  9999-12-31  100001  123.0       both
2   1222-09-27  9999-12-31  999999  125.0       left_only
3   1998-09-27  9999-12-31  100000  NaN         right_only
```

Comment: Hello Chris, I believe this happens:

File "<ipython-input-17-652c06e841b0>", line 1
    csv1[_merge'] == 'left_only'
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I missed a single quote on the left side of _merge, updated.

Comment: Hello Chris, the code works itself but doesn't produce the intended result of left join, null. I think your code is just normal left join

Comment: It's an outer join, which returns everything from both sides, and you can filter for left only, right only, or  both.  There are no records in your data set that match on all 3 columns.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: left join, null is describing rows from only the left data frame, exclusive to it. normal left join is inclusive of rows that are in the right data frame, but i need the former rather than the latter

Comment: I know what it is, it's a left anti join.  I believe what's happened is that my df2 is missing the last digit of the second ITEMID, let me update the answer.

Comment: @BigBrainAlgorithms Check it out now

Comment: Awesome Chris! However, I think there was an error in editing perhaps, it is still the same code in the answer: "df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['STARTDATE','ENDDATE','ITEMID'], indicator=True)"